# Techniques for counting items in a category

Tags: sql

I'm building an e-shop using [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system), and wanted to know what is the most *efficient* way to represent the number of items in a particular category? So for instance, my category menu would look something like this:

> - Books (212)
> - MP3 players (13)
> - Footwear (562)

What techniques do you use to get those numbers? I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1, but I assume the mechanics should be similar throughout all DBMSs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT category, count(*)
FROM items
GROUP BY category
```

This will count the number of items in the table for each category.

Comment: But is the GROUP BY efficient enough to be executed every time the page gets loaded?

Comment: In all likelihood, yes. If your tables are exceptionally large you could store the category counts in another table, being sure to update it any time items are added, deleted, or modified.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the actual query for what you want is:

```
SELECT category || ' (' || cast(count(*) as varchar(255)) || ')' as entry
FROM items
GROUP BY category
```

Comment: A matter of taste, maybe, but I would have my presentation layer handle the parentheses, and not make this string manipulation part of the query.

Comment: I agree it is a matter of taste.  However, it happens to be the answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: I agree with Tim, good application has well distinguished logical layers. And the example I gave was just for the clarification purpose, not how I'm going to represent it in real life. Therefore I must accept the other answer. Cheers